# How i run loop for laravel recursive relationship

Tags: php, laravel, relationship

[This is comments table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFwoK.png)

This is my laravel relation -

```
public function children()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Comment::class, 'parent_id', 'id');
}

public function allChildren()
{
    return $this->children()->with('allChildren');
}
```

**How can i run recursive foreach loop for this so i can print comments of comments.**

Answer (score 1):

you know that relations jobs is to make it easy to prepare the query you're running.

if it loops infinitely during the preparation, the query will never start running.

At some point, you will have to choose how many level you need to recover.

For a 4 levels example:

```
Post::with('comments.children.children.children').get();
```

Comment: but i need loop where there is no limit of levels like instagram

Comment: @Ranveer Instagram does it with Javascript. Infinite scroll, not an infinite query. There are solutions to get all the comments of the post by having all the comments (no matter their level) have a foreign key to the post in question(getting them with `Post::with('comments')` and then reorder the results into a hierarchical structure with parent/children comments via code.